# Redirect entire route group to another url?

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-routing

Given a route group like `Route::group(['prefix' => 'foo',])` how would I redirect all routes under this group to `domain.com`?

I've tried:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'foo'], function() {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return Redirect::to('http://domain.com');
    });
});
```

But that would only redirect myoldsite.com/foo to domain.com, anything such as myoldsite.com/foo/deeper/path would just be a 404. Is there a way to catch all sub routes and redirect them?

Answer (score 2):

You can add a catch-all parameter.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'foo'], function() {
    Route::get('/{atsl}', function ($atsl) {
        return Redirect::to('http://domain.com');
    });
});
```